# Gradient descent proof: show that $f(x^k) - f(x^*) \leq \|x^0 - x^*\|_2^2/2\alpha k$

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I am going through the proof of the convergence rate of gradient descent, following [this link](https://cims.nyu.edu/~cfgranda/pages/OBDA_spring16/material/optimization_algorithms.pdf).

However, I am completely stuck on how the author went from equation (18) to equation (19) (boxed in red).

**Can someone please provide some assistance to the derivation of equation (19).**

The proof is attached below:

[image]

**Per request, the content of Corollary 2.6 is shown below (without proof, but is a well-known bound for GD)**

[image]

Comment: And what is the content of Corollary 2.6?

Comment: @Thomas Hi, I have updated my question to include this corollary.

Comment: Unrelated comment, but the FISTA convergence plot in figure 7 of these notes looks weird to me. The lowest objective function value is obtained around iteration 30, and then the algorithm appears to be converging to a non-optimal value. Based on my experience implementing this algorithm (to solve the same problem), I think there's a bug in the code that generated figure 7.

Comment: As @Onetimething mentioned, we go from (18) to (19) by "completing the square". It's similar to the technique we learn in precalculus where we rewrite $x^2 + bx$ as $(x + \frac{b}{2})^2 - \frac{b^2}{4}$. When working with vectors, we can rewrite $\| x \|^2 + \langle b, x \rangle$ as $\| x + \frac{b}{2} \|^2 - \|b\|^2/4$.

Comment: What is difficult to understand for me is that there is an equality sign. If it were just an inequality than the Lipshitz condition yields $||\nabla f|| \le L$ and you could use the relation between the $\alpha$ and $L$. Since, in the end, you only need an inequality, I'd follow that approach.

Comment: There is another proof of this result at the bottom of the page in https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/03/28/smoothfunctions/ However, this one is even harder to follow since the proof goes wild half way through. So better to get this one working first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that (19), by the binomial formula, is equal to
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2\alpha}\left(||x^{(i-1)} - x^*||^2_2 
- ||x^{(i-1)} - x^* - \alpha \nabla f(x^{(i-1)}||^2_2) \right)=
\frac{1}{2\alpha}\left(||x^{(i-1)} - x^*||^2_2  
- ||x^{(i-1)} - x^*||^2_2 +2\alpha ||\nabla f(x^{(i-1)})||_2||x^{(i-1)} - x^*||_2 - \alpha^2 ||\nabla f(x^{(i-1)})||^2\right)=  ||\nabla f(x^{(i-1)})||_2||x^{(i-1)} - x^*||_2 -\frac{\alpha}{2}||\nabla f(x^{(i-1)})||_2^2
\end{eqnarray}
This is $\ge (18)$, by Cauchy-Schwartz (but in general not $=$).

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment, but I don't have enough flair. Here are some suggestions. It's something similar to ''completing the squares'' argument for scalars. Try working backwards to simplify (19), you can get to equation (18) by noting (a) $\|x\|^2 = x^T x$ and (b) $x^Ty = y^Tx$ (for real vectors at least).

Or, said another way, if you really want to go from (18) to (19), you could, add and subtract $\|x^{(i-1)} - x^*\|^2$ and proceed from there by appropriately normalizing using $\alpha$.

Comment: You are right, I should just try to reverse engineer that equation and see what steps they used. Even then I have a hard time believing that (18) = (19) instead of (18) <= (19).

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the proofs are reverse engineered since you know what convergence you would like to show. However, as an added point, intuitively, (18) is something like $-2ab + b^2$. And you just need to find the right $c$ and $d$ to make it $c^2 - d^2$.